# What data-type should I use to store monetary values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've read I should use **money**, but in todays fast paced world maybe that's obsolete now.

What should I use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, money should still work.

Comment: Money works but has problems such as storing 4 decimal places but it appearing that it stores only 2 when the values store are in whole cents...

Comment: what !!?? If the value is in whole cents there are only two.

Comment: If a developer inserts a bunch of values to a `money` column, such as `VALUES (12.34), (10.79), (18.43)`, then selects them, he will see those values as entered, not as `12.3400, 10.7900, 18.4300`. This is a serious problem because it leads him to believe that the `money` data type only stores 2 decimal places. Then he does `INSERT MyTable (PurchaseAmount) SELECT Shares * PricePerShare` without truncating to 2 decimal places. Oops! Also, money can be divided by money (I want to spent $1000 on shares costing $36 each) and multiplied (I want to calculate standard deviation).

Comment: If the data type is `decimal(12, 4)` instead of `money`, SELECTing will show the values correctly with the extra zeroes. If the data type is `decimal(10, 2)`, then he can't insert erroneous values. There is no clear winning case for `money` given these serious problems.

Comment: Update: (sorry, I meant to say when the values stored are in fractions of a cent). Also, try `Convert(varchar(100), Convert(money, 246000.4879))` to see an additional problem vector. Must be `Convert(varchar(100), Convert(money, 246000.4879), 2)` to display all 4 digits.

Comment: @ErikIe,  Sorry, any developer who does not understand the difference between values stored in database and formatted values for display in an application should not be messing with this... Try `Declare @m Money = 123.45`  `Select  str(@m, 8, 4)`  or, even better, Try `Declare @m Money = 123.45`  `Select  str(@m, 12, 9)`  The value as formatted for display has little to do with the value stored....  It is not meaningfull to even discuss the number of decimals "Stored" ...  If you save the value 2 in a field of type Numeric(12,11), do you really think it not storing the eleven zeroes?

Comment: The data type *should* have a LOT to do with the value stored, and `money` hides this. I have no personal understanding problem, but the fact is that many software development companies are full of developers who don't really understand databases, and they're great developers even so. `money` is a horrible data type because it *hides* the precision and scale behind a mask. Your example of `numeric(12,11)` is not a good one because the developer (who is inexperienced in SQL Server, but otherwise reasonably or very intelligent) can see that there are 11 decimal places, unlike with `money`.

Comment: The data type has EVERYTHING to do with the data stored, but it has NOTHING to do with how the data is formatted to be displayed.  And are you really saying it is horrible because it doesn't specify the precision ion the name? If that was a valid criterion, then float, real, decimal (with no precision specified) and Numeric, and Integer, SmallInt and Tinyint are also horrible.  They don't specify the size and scope of what they are either. Should integer be named Int32 ?  what about datetime and smallDatetime? should they be named datetime200ms and datetime2sec ??

Comment: Some languages (C# for example), do in fact do add stuff like that to the names of datatypes. But it is a convenience - nothing more. There are many plenty of things about database implementations that are a lot more worth complaining about than ensuring that the name of a datatype communicates the specifications. There are many many things developers ought to know, a long litany of details, and we certainly can't expect everyone to know all of them, but what he definitions of the datatypes are, or at least how to look that info up, should be near the bottom of the list.

Comment: `money` is horrible because all the actual real-world money, outside of perhaps specific financial environments, comes with 2 decimal places. `money` comes with 4. It's that simple, Charles. You're completely missing the point at each step. `Money` offers zero benefit over `decimal`, and it is obscure to boot (a drawback). So it loses, absolutely and completely. Don't use it and you'll have a better database, better code, and fewer confused developers. The same can't be said for the other data types you mentioned.

Comment: In a real-world problem in a system I have worked in, developers accidentally inserted sub-cent fractions such as 12.4567 (when 12.45 or 12.46 would have been okay, as it was the result of a calculation). This caused problems when customer balances didn't add up correctly, or were told they still owed $0, and so on, or the financial system couldn't reconcile/close out properly. But *you couldn't see this in the database* because the `money` data type was used and simple selects on that don't show the hidden digits.

Answer (score 13):

Papuccino,

I don't recommend the types money and smallmoney unless you are certain the only arithmetic you plan to do is addition and subtraction. If you might be dealing with exchange rates, percentages, and so on, you risk real problems with these types.

Here's just one small example to show you a difference between using money, decimal, and float when division is involved. It's possible to come up with examples where the difference is much more dramatic.

```
declare @m1 money, @m2 money, @m3 money
declare @d1 decimal(19,4), @d2 decimal(19,4), @d3 decimal(19,4)
declare @f1 float, @f2 float, @f3 float;
set @m1 = 1.00;
set @m2 = 345.00;
set @m3 = @m1/@m2;
set @d1 = 1.00;
set @d2 = 345.00;
set @d3 = @d1/@d2;
set @f1 = 1.00;
set @f2 = 345.00;
set @f3 = @f1/@f2;
select @m3, @d3, @f3;
```

Result: 0.0028   0.0029     0.00289855072463768

Depending on the industry, there may be guidelines or regulations to help you decide on the right data type. There is no one right answer.

**Added remarks:**

You are correct that money/money should not be money, but SQL Server (inexplicably) produces  exactly that result: type money from the quotient of two money values. This is bogus, but as you see from the example below, it is what you get, even though it makes no sense:

```
declare @m1 money, @m2 money;
declare @d1 decimal(19,4), @d2 decimal(19,4);
set @m1 = 1.00;
set @m2 = 345.00;
set @d1 = 1.00;
set @d2 = 345.00;
select @m1/@m2, @d1/@d2
```

Result: 0.0028  0.0028985507246376811

The result with type money, 0.0028, is 3-4% less than the correct result.

Of course, there are many situations where you need to divide currency values. The danger of using the money type is that the quotient is the wrong type (and an answer not close enough to the correct one). Examples of questions that require dividing currency:

Suppose you exchange 320 Yuan and the bank gives you 47.3 US dollars. What is the exchange rate you've been given?

Suppose you invest $23 and a year later it's worth $31. What is your percent rate of return?

Both of these calculations require dividing currency values.

Comment: I believe this is bogus example... There is no real-wprl fucntion where you would be required to divide Money by Money and get Money as an outout. This is meaningless...  It's like saying that 3 pears / 2 pears = 1.5 pears.  This is wrong.  Units matter.

Comment: If you are doing currency conversions at the database layer, choosing between int, float, and decimal types is the least of your problems.

Comment: Saying that `money` should not be used because of division issues is like saying `int` shouldn't be used because of division issues. Indeed, `select 9 / 10` yields zero which is terribly wrong! And yet we use `int`s all the time, you just need to understand what integer division is. `Money` doesn't change precision during division, just like `int`. So the digits beyond the four decimal points are lost, just like they are lost beyond zero decimal points in `int`.

Comment: `Decimal`, on the other hand, uses [complicated rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms190476(v=sql.90)) for changing its precision during division. According to those, `decimal(19,4) / decimal(19,4)` is `decimal(38,19)` which stores the result up to the 19th decimal point, which is then *rounded* upon being stored in `decimal(19,4)` - yet another `decimal` rule regarding shifting precisions. So there is nothing to say that `money` has issues and `decimal` doesn't. They are simply different.

Answer (score 2):

Why should [money](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933242(SQL.80).aspx) be obsolete?  It goes up to over 900 trillions, hundreds of times the Federal Government's budget -- what kind of money amounts do you possibly need to store?-) (I guess that maybe [Zimbabwe dollars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zimbabwean_dollar) might eventually have been a problem, but they kept resetting it by multiples of billions and trillions, and last April it was finally suspended; they use US dollars or other foreign currencies now for payments & accounting in Zimbabwe).

Comment: While maximum magnitude is important I think that decimal accuracy is just as important.  I believe the IRS suggests that money should be calculated to 4 decimal places.  Which the money type does.

Comment: Yep, 1 part in 10,000 -- but I can't believe the OP could have thought THAT would be obsoleted (by what...?), so I guessed they were worried about large amounts (if Zimbabwe dollars hadn't been so often reset, 900 trillions of them wouldn't buy a toothpick;-).

Comment: "It goes up to over 900 trillions, hundreds of times the Federal Government's budget..." But how does it compare to the Federal debt? :P

Comment: Close to 100 times larger -- cfr http://www.brillig.com/debt_clock/ -- what's ur POINT?!-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree money divided by money is bogus. But money divided by days is real. If you are dividing small amounts of money by the number of days you need to spead the cost, it is most important to keep watch of this phenomenon. I cast/convert money to float, do computation before eventually storing the end result to money data type. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It surprises me that nobody mentioned it before.

[`money`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx) is 8 bytes. 
[`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187746.aspx) is 5, 9, 13 or 17 bytes depending on precision (precision is not the number of decimal digits after the decimal point, it is the maximum total number of decimal digits that will be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point). So, to mimic range of values that `money` supports (-922,337,203,685,477.5808 to 922,337,203,685,477.5807) you need `decimal(19,4)`.

```
+-------------------+---------------+
| decimal precision | Storage bytes |
+-------------------+---------------+
| 1 - 9             |             5 |
| 10-19             |             9 |
| 20-28             |            13 |
| 29-38             |            17 |
+-------------------+---------------+
```

If storing 9 bytes instead of 8 doesn't seem like a big deal, you should keep in mind that `money` is a native processor type, like 64-bit `bigint`, but `decimal` is not. It means that summing up billions of `money` values would be faster than summing up `decimal` values. Performing other calculations like division would have even larger difference.

On my virtual machine with SQL Server 2014 Express I ran this simple test.
`dbo.Numbers` is a table with 10,000 rows with one `int` column `Number` with values from 1 to 10,000.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Numbers](
    [Number] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Numbers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Number] ASC
))
```

I ran this in SQL Sentry Plan Explorer:

```
DECLARE @VarM money = 1234.5678;

SELECT
    AVG(@VarM / N1.Number)
FROM 
    dbo.Numbers AS N1
    CROSS JOIN dbo.Numbers AS N2
;


DECLARE @VarD decimal(19,4) = 1234.5678;

SELECT
    AVG(@VarD / N1.Number)
FROM 
    dbo.Numbers AS N1
    CROSS JOIN dbo.Numbers AS N2
;
```

Execution plan is the same for both queries (well, there are different implicit conversions of `Number`: to `money` and `decimal`), but run time is 15 seconds vs. 40 seconds. It is quite noticeable for me.

[image: money vs decimal]

---

Of course, you need to know that `money` has only 4 decimal places. If you perform calculations you need to be aware of the types (and their precedence, i.e. what is implicitly converted into what) and make sure that intermediate results are of the appropriate type by casting operands into proper types if needed. This warning applies to calculations with any types, not just `money`. When you divide two `int` values you should know that result is `int` and not be surprised that `4 / 5 = 0`.