# What data type should be used for currency type of calculation

Tags: sql-server, database-design, types

In my table I would like to define an amount field.  This field is usually a number with only 2 decimal places

e.g.
Amount can be up to 999,999,999.99 or 999,999,999

This field is multiplied by a rate.

The rate field can be be 1.11 or 0.1234 (2 decimal or 4 decimal places)

Then another field will hold the total amount that rounds the result up to 2 decimal places.  If the total amount is 2.516, save result as 2.51.  If total amount is 2.556, save result as 2.56

What data types should I use for the following fields?
1. Amount
2. Rate
3. Total Amount

I have seen examples defined as FLOAT, decimal, money.

Answer (score 7):

I would always choose DECIMAL when given those options, especially when dealing with currency. Reasons:

- DECIMAL can be more flexible than MONEY; the latter is fixed to 4 decimal places; usually you want less, but sometimes more (penny trading, converting euros to yen, etc).
- FLOAT has a much wider range of approximation, which can lead to funny results - I don't get that result for that specific calculation on current versions, BTW, but there are other examples I'm sure, probably in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server).
- MONEY can lose important precision. Try this:

  ```
  SELECT [money]   = $0.46 / $345.70, 
         [decimal] =  0.46 /  345.70;
  ```

  Also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355418/what-data-type-should-i-use-to-store-monetary-values) (look beyond the accepted answer).
- More information in the following posts:

  - [Performance / Storage Comparisons : MONEY vs. DECIMAL](https://sqlblog.org/2008/04/27/performance-storage-comparisons-money-vs-decimal) (sorry for missing images)
  - [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: So I should use
Amount decimal (19,2)
Rate decimal (19,4)
Total_Amount decimal (19,2)

Comment: @Charles if your max amount can be 999,999,999.99 then DECIMAL(11,2) should be sufficient.

Comment: sometimes I had this interface as when I hit my keyboard keys to return, it goes ahead and adds a comment when I am not finish and all I want to do is put a next line.  Anyways, how would I define the rate field properly when it could be 2 decimal places or 4?  Would it be decimal (3,4)

Comment: If it might be 2 or might be 4, you'll need to always store 4. Also 3,4 is not possible. The first number is total number of digits; the second is number to the right of the decimal. So perhaps 13,4 is what you need if you might need to store 999,999,999.9999.

Comment: For that particular field e.g. rate field, I would only need to define it as Decimal (6,4) for 99.9999 as that would be my max entry...correct? so my range entered is for my purpose positive numbers only, 0.0001 to 99.9999

Comment: @Charles sounds reasonable, yep. You should create a test table and then try to insert your entire range of possible values for the various columns. I don't know what all of those are, so it will be tedious to keep asking me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Most systems I have worked with, both existing and new use Decimal with 4 decimal places.