# SQL Server CEILING of 100 = 101?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've found a really weird behavior in SQL Server 2012, the `CEILING` of 100 gives me 101 and sometimes 100.

I need to get the ceiling of a number considering 2 decimals, that means convert a 0.254 to 0.26

So I tried to run

```
SELECT CEILING(field * 100.0) / 100.0 
FROM Table
```

This should work, and it does, at least for most of the data.

Any idea on how to solve it?

[image: This is an example of the weird behavior]

Comment: try to use [round(field, 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) instead of floating point math

Comment: ROUND will not return the ceiling or floor (I have the same issue with FLOOR)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165358/sql-server-strange-ceiling-behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing here is floating point errors. When you store a number in a floating point column, it isn't exact, so the number 1 may actually be 1.0000000000000000000000001. So multiplying it by 100 gives you a number a tiny bit greater than 100, hence `CEILING` rounds it up to 101.

The solution is to ROUND the number first which will remove the floating point errors. Note I have used 5 as the number of decimal places, you will need to decide on your own value of precision.

```
SELECT CEILING(ROUND(field,5)*100.0)/100.0 FROM Table
```

Comment: ¿should I round it to 10 decimals before applying the CEILING? this seems like a workaround. how should I suppose to handle this correctly?

Comment: Maybe not 10, how many do you really need in your application? Anything more than 2 decimal places is rarely required, but only you know your problem domain.