# Specify the culture used within the "With Clause" of OpenJSON

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I live in Denmark. Here the Thousand separator  is a dot (.), and we use comma (,) as comma-separator.

I know that you can use TRY_PARSE to convert a varchar into a money/float value.

An example:

```sql
declare
    @JSON varchar(max)= 
    '
    {
        "Data Table":
        [
            {
                "Value" : "27.123,49"
            }
        ]
    }
    '

select  
    TRY_PARSE(Value as money using 'da-dk') "Correct Value"
FROM OpenJson(@json, '$."Data Table"')
WITH
(
    "Value" nvarchar(255)   N'$."Value"'
)

select  
    Value "Wrong Value"
FROM OpenJson(@json, '$."Data Table"')
WITH
(
    "Value" money   N'$."Value"'
)
```

This query gives me two results

[image]

My question is: Can I control the culture in the WiTH Clause of OpenJSON, so I get the correct result without having to use TRY_PARSE?

Target: SQL Server 2019

Comment: I didn't see anything in the documentation that indicates it's possible.

Comment: Not directly in OPENJSON(), no. ECMA-404 JSON Data Interchange Syntax specifically defines the decimal point as the U+002E `.` character - and doesn't provide for cultural allowances - which is why you're having to define culture-specific values as strings in the first place.

Comment: No you cannot do this. The correct way to do it is only using `TRY_PARSE` or `TRY_CONVERT`. Side note: [avoid `money` as it has weird rounding issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355418/what-data-type-should-i-use-to-store-monetary-values), use `decimal` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did look in the documentation, and tried Google before asking a question, here. My question was bacilly: Did   I miss sometihng. 

And  @Charlieface tha. for theheads up om money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly in OPENJSON(), no. ECMA-404 JSON Data Interchange Syntax specifically defines the decimal point as the U+002E . character - and doesn't provide for cultural allowances - which is why you're having to define culture-specific values as strings in the first place.

The correct way to do it is only using [TRY_PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or TRY_CONVERT. eg

```
select try_parse('27.123,49' as money using 'da-DK')
```