# Cast varchar into money or at least numeric

Tags: sql, t-sql, casting

I have a varchar value that needs to be casted into a money value.
Tee value I like to cast looks like this:

[image]

I thought this should work

```
select 
cast(replace([Gross value transactions], '$','')as numeric) as amount
from xy
```

I get the following error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Is this because of the commas and dots?
Like in $2,535,000.00?
How do I get rid of this?
Can I directly cast it as money?

@Thom A
I tried actually to cast it into money directly:

```
 ,cast([Gross value transactions] as money) as amount
```

I got the following Error Message: Cannot convert a char value to money.

Not much more luck with this:

```
,cast(replace(replace(replace([Gross value transactions (NZD)], '$',''), ',',''), '.','') as numeric) as amount
```

Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

How can I cast it sucessfully?

Comment: `CAST` it to a `money` first then a `numeric`/`decimal`, as the `money` data type allows currency characters and thousand separators.

Comment: Don't use money, https://blog.greglow.com/2018/01/15/sql-newbie-mistake-1-using-float-instead-decimal/

Comment: why does the repace function not work?

Comment: @ThomA - how do I do that ?

Comment: @jarlh to *store* the data, correct, but the OP has already made the incorrect choice to store the monetary value as a `varchar`. The *real* solution is the fix the design and store it in a `decimal` with an appropriate precision and scale (perhaps a `decimal(18,4)`). Casting the `money` as a middleman isn't the same as store is as `money`.

Comment: *"Cannot convert a char value to money."* Sounds like you have some bad data in your column; another reason why using a `varchar` is a *terrible* idea for monetary values. You can use `TRY_CAST`/`TRY_CONVERT` but any bad data will end up being `NULL`; you really need to fix your design and fix the bad data.

Comment: @jarlh That is a rather poor article that first discusses that using *`float`* is wrong, and then makes an implicit unfounded assumption, at a glance, that using `money` is almost equally wrong and that the author dislikes it too because it has relationships with currency symbols, and proceeds to show that using `decimal` is correct. Why would `money`, being a fixed-point data type, be inferior to `decimal(18,4)` which is also a fixed-point data type?

Comment: @GSerg `money` has rounding issues, which are not outlined in that article, but are elsewhere https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355418/what-data-type-should-i-use-to-store-monetary-values

Comment: @Charlieface Arguably, it's the decimal that has [non straightforward division](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424052/11683). When you divide two `decimal(19,4)`s, the result is typed as `decimal(38,19)` according to the [complicated rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms190476(v=sql.90)). That result is then rounded to `decimal(19,4)`. `Money`, on the other hand, does not change its precision throughout, so the digits that fall behind the four decimal places are ignored. Just like it is with the integer division.

Answer (score 0):

Test sample

```
[Gross value transactions]: $2,535,000.11
```

Cast to money

```
SELECT cast([Gross value transactions] as money) as amount
FROM [dbo].[XY]
-- amount: 2535000.11
```

Cast to numeric/decimal

```
-- do not replace '.'
SELECT cast(replace(replace([Gross value transactions], '$',''), ',','')as numeric(18,2)) as amount
FROM [dbo].[XY]
-- amount: 2535000.11
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select parse([Gross value transactions] as money using 'en-us')
from xy;
```